# Tumblr: ask and custom pages

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

I'm designing a theme but whenever I go to the ask page or a custom/nonexistent page, it shows up on the permalinkpage.. with the little sidebar and everything that I have set up for that.. Does anyone know any way to keep them separate from that so it just shows up in the white box like everything else does?

http://iveytesting3.tumblr.com/ask

^the theme I'm working on

sigh, I found a very annoying way to get around it.. but I'd still like to know if there is an easier way?

Apparently, tumblr has the ask, submit, and custom/static pages load up on the permalink page for text posts.. and to get around the styling for the permalink page for text posts that I had done, I had to insert a BUNCH of {block:Date} tags around everything.. just to pull out the {title} and the {body} tags for the text post...

Anyone know an easier way though?

Comment: Use a custom layout on the page instead of standard layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the unwanted extra items you don't want to show in the index block?

{block:Indexpage}

blah blah blah

{/block:Indexpage}